# Add opp id field into ContentVersion Post Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, contentversion

i am trying to add the opp id for a content version to the content version once it is created

i am running into issues where the record is read only, how can i update this object when it seems to be uncommited to the database

Below is the code that should work but errors

```
trigger ContentLinkHandoverAttachParentv2 on ContentVersion (before update) {

    For(ContentVersion cv : trigger.new){

        Contentdocumentlink CDL = [SELECT linkedentityid FROM ContentDocumentLink Where contentdocumentid = :cv.contentdocumentid limit 1];

        String newid = cdl.LinkedEntityId;

        System.debug(CDL);

        if(newid.startsWith('006')){

            cv.AssociatedOppLinkID__c = cdl.LinkedEntityId;

        }
    }

}
```

I have also tried from the ContentDocumnetLink Side but run into similar issues

```
    trigger ContentLinkHandoverAttachParent on ContentDocumentLink (After insert) {
    List<ContentVersion> CVtoadd = New List<ContentVersion>();

    For(ContentDocumentLink cdl : trigger.new){    

        String linkedString = (String)cdl.get(Schema.ContentDocumentLink.linkedEntityid);    

        id linkedid = (id)cdl.get(Schema.ContentDocumentLink.linkedEntityid);
        ContentVersion Record = (ContentVersion)cdl.get(Schema.ContentDocumentLink.contentdocumentid);    


        if(LinkedString.startsWith('006')){

            ContentVersion CV = record;
            cv.AssociatedOppLinkID__c = linkedid;

            CVtoadd.add(cv);
        }
    }
update CVtoadd;        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this lovely article by Jeff Douglass the relationship field in triggers aren't populated till after they've been saved : http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/23/relationship-lookup-objects-in-triggers-are-null/

For your first bit of code this would mean that you first have to query the contentversions in order to get the contentdocumentids. After that you can query the contentdocumentlinks.

As a side note, it is best practice to perform all queries outside of for loops. This is especially true for triggers. If you don't do that you may run into governor limits rather easily.

As a bonus, there is actually a nicer way to check if an id is of the opportunity type.

```
if(cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType() == Schema.Opportunity.getSObjectType()){
// whatever your code is supposed to do when it's an opportunity. 
}
```